# Knitr not displaying graph when out.width or out.height set

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I've already posted this question, but it lacked a MWE, so I've decided to delete the old question and post a new one, since the old one had to be almost completely rewritten.

I'm trying to typeset an `.Rmd` research report into pdf using `knitr`. I'd like to include a graph created in `ggplot`.

If I include the `out.width` or `out.height` chunk options, the graph isn't present in the output pdf document.

Here's the MWE:

1) data creation:

```
datas <- data.frame(x = rep(1:30), y = rep(40:69))
save(datas, file = 'datas.RData')
```

2) Main file - `file.Rmd`:

````
---
author: "NN"
title: "Title"
fontsize: 14pt
geometry: margin=2cm
output: pdf_document
header-includes: |
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{bookman}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{tabu}
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{threeparttablex}
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \captionsetup[table]{width=\textwidth}
    \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tablica}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Slika}
---
```{r setup, echo = F, include = F}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
# knitr setup
opts_chunk$set(prompt = T, background = '#E5E8E8', dpi = 600, fig.width = 12, dev = 'pdf')
options(digits = 3)

# packages
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(wrapr)
library(readxl)
library(magrittr)
library(psych)
library(ggpubr)

# loading the data
load('datas.RData')
```
sample text

```{r desk_stat, child = 'file_d.Rmd'}
```
````

3) Sub-file (the one containing the plot) - `file_d.Rmd`:

````
```{r, fig.cap = '\\label{bar-znanje-visina}Some label.', cache = T, out.width = '.49\\linewidth'}
ggplot(datas,
       aes(x = x)) +
    geom_bar()
```
````

If I typeset it with these options, the image in the `.md` file is included with:

```
<embed src="figure/unnamed-chunk-1-1.pdf" title="\label{bar-znanje-visina}Some label." alt="\label{bar-znanje-visina}Some label." width=".49\linewidth" type="application/pdf" />
```

An the output pdf looks like this:

[image: output with out.width]

If I typeset the output without the `out.width` option, the image in the `.md` file is included with:

```
![\label{bar-znanje-visina}Some label.](figure/unnamed-chunk-1-1.pdf)
```

And the output pdf looks like this:

[image: output without out.width]

I'm knitting the .Rmd file with

```
Rscript -e 'library(knitr); opts_knit$set(out.format = "latex"); knit("file.Rmd")'
```

Session info:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Manjaro Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8        LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=hr_HR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8     
 [5] LC_MONETARY=hr_HR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8    
 [7] LC_PAPER=hr_HR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=hr_HR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] kableExtra_0.9.0 knitr_1.20       nvimcom_0.9-72  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16      rstudioapi_0.7    xml2_1.2.0        magrittr_1.5     
 [5] hms_0.4.2         rvest_0.3.2       munsell_0.4.3     viridisLite_0.3.0
 [9] colorspace_1.3-2  R6_2.2.2          rlang_0.2.0       plyr_1.8.4       
[13] stringr_1.3.0     httr_1.3.1        tools_3.4.3       htmltools_0.3.6  
[17] rprojroot_1.3-2   digest_0.6.15     tibble_1.4.2      readr_1.1.1      
[21] evaluate_0.10.1   rmarkdown_1.9     stringi_1.1.7     compiler_3.4.3   
[25] pillar_1.2.1      scales_0.5.0      backports_1.1.2   pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

EDIT: Update

I tried typesetting Yihui's minimal `.Rnw` [example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw) and it works just fine. I also tried modifying it so that it display the graph from the MWE, and it also works. I've also noticed that setting `keep_tex = true` doesn't do anything when compiling an `.Rmd` file. No `tex` file is created.

Comment: The `knit()`command produces a `md` file. How do you process this file? Note that the PDF I get via the knit button in RStudio is fine (Debian stable).

Comment: I process the `.md` file with `pandoc -o filename.pdf filename.md`. Not using RStudio, but Vim as editor, but don't think that should matter. Does RStudio have some pandoc settings that should be observed?

Comment: The pandoc command line used in RStudio is rather long. I would suggest using `rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd")` or the `render.r` script from `littler`.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot! I tried using `knitr::pandoc`, but that didn't work. `render` works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `knitr::knit()` it is easier to use `rmarkdown::render()`. You can either call it directly

```
Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd")'
```

or indirectly using an example script from the `littler` package

```
render.r file.Rmd
```

on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you're always knittng to a pdf, you can try setting `out.width = '49%'` in the code chunk settings. You can also try adjusting the `fig.width =` setting in the code chunk instead, which takes in the size of the figure width in inches. If all that doesn't work I would also [take a look](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html) at the `grid.arrange()` function from the gridExtra package

Also your problem is not reproducible. When I run your code on my Win10 machine, I get the following output.

[image: reproduced_example]

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with `out.width = 49%`. Maybe it's a Linux thing? I've just noticed that my TeXlive version is still from 2017, so I'll try to update it to the 2018 version and report back.

Comment: The problem persists with R 3.5 and TeXlive 2018.47471-1

Comment: Also, just noticed that your code has a background (which isn't present in my pdf) and that the author is in italics. What's going ooon?

Comment: I tried typesetting Yihui's minimal `.Rnw` [example] (https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw) and it works just fine. I also tried modifying it so that it display the graph from the MWE, and it also works. I've also noticed that setting `keep_tex = true` doesn't do anything when compiling an `.Rmd` file. No `tex` file is created.